# AngularJS get element into view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll

I have a very wide `div` with a lot of elements. When I press a button, I want it to come into view? `$anchorscroll` doesn't seem to work this way is there anything I can use?

Something for horizontal scrolling to an element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
var app = angular.module("sa", []);

app.controller("FooController", function($scope) {

  $scope.scrollH = function() {
    var parent = document.querySelector("#parent");
    var focusable = document.querySelector("#focusme");

    var parentLeft = parent.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    var focusableLeft = focusable.getBoundingClientRect().left;

    parent.scrollLeft = focusableLeft - parentLeft;
  };
});
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  overflow: auto;
}
#child {
  width: 1200px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="sa" ng-controller="FooController">
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
      Etiam feugiat lorem non metus. Sed cursus turpis vitae tortor. Vestibulum volutpat, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. Sed libero. <strong id="focusme">I need to be scroll horizontally.</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#" ng-click="scrollH()">Scroll horizontally</a>
</div>
```

You can wrap it as a directive to make code common.

Comment: great I had to do a bit of modification but it helped alot :)